# two array element save in same tabel through php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two array value in two variable. I want to save both in table
simultaneously for this i used this code:

```
//$ec_country=$request->input('exc');
//$ey=$request->input('exy');

//In current case its comming Null

foreach (array_combine($c,$y) as $e1=>$y1) 
{
    DB::table('table')->insert([
        ['id' => $id, 'c_id' => $y1,'yr'=>$y1,'added_date'=>$date]
    ]);
}
```

My html code is :

```
<div class="form-group row no-padding ">
@foreach($result['c'] as $ed)
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 ">
    <label class="fvb">ec</label>
    <select name="EC[]" class="form-control " id="ec">
        @foreach($result['te'] as $tec)
        <option value="{{tce->id}}" > {{$tce->ce}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="english">Years</label>
    <select name="ey[]" id="er" class="form-control">
        @for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
        <option value="{{$i}}"  >{{ $i}}</option>
        @endfor
    </select>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Its working fine when I have value in both array but when array is
blank its returning me error like:

```
array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

So my question is that is there any other way to solve this problem
instead of `array_combine()` using `foreach` loop ??

Please help me related this.

Comment: `$exp_country` is null, please check that.

Comment: yes its blank in my database..

Comment: here i dont want array_combine i want this solution through foreach loop

Comment: what you mean by `foreach` loop?

Comment: Like This :foreach ($a as $index => $value)
{
    echo $a[$index] .' '. $b[$index];
}

Comment: can you add sample data in question or in comment for this two variable $exp_country , $exp_year?

Comment: You could put an `if` statement before like this: `if(is_null($blank_array)` then perform action.

Comment: Use `array_merge($exp_country,$exp_year)` not `array_combine()`.

Comment: @Param Bhat  updated my question have alook...

Comment: array_combine only will work for you when both array contains equal number of elements. in your case one is returning null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead of [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Try it like this:

```
if(!empty($ec && $ey)) {
  foreach (array_merge($ec,$ey) as $e=>$y) 
  {
    DB::table('table')->insert([
        ['wid' => $id, 'cid' => $expcont,'ey'=>$y,'added_date'=>$date]
    ]);
  }
} else {
  return "Any return statement!";
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: getting erroe after this:  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: That means you don't have array `$exp_country`!

Comment: in my case its comming null .. so how can i check the variables for null or not by if..else

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) not [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

**array_merge** actually gather two array and **array_combine** creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

Comment: but in case when variable getting null value its not working retuirning me error

Comment: Well, before using this array_merge function, you better check the variables for null or not by if..else.

Comment: ??how can i check variable for null value .. can u please help me related this

Comment: Mention your two array in the question.

Comment: already mention but i am asking about that case when i am getting null value in both variable